# Process.HasExited race condition

Tags: c#, process, synchronization, race-condition

I have an instance of `System.Diagnostics.Process` which was created via `Process.GetProcessesByName`.

After I sucessfully open the process, I perform various operations, such as reading its memory and the window title.

This operations are constantly executed based on a timer, by which I mean the `Timer.Elapsed` event handler is the source of the process operations.

Now, I noticed that I have a race condition that I've been unable to solve using anything I know. Here is how it happens:

```
timerElapsedEvent(...) {

    if (!process.HasExited) {

        process.Refresh(); // Update title.
        var title = process.MainWindowTitle;
    }

}
```

If the process is running, and my code enters the `if` block, there is a small chance the process might exit before the `process.MainWindowTitle` call is executed, which would cause an exception.

**What I need is a way to somehow capture the exit event of the process and keep it alive untill it is safe to close it without crashing my application which is monitoring it, thus making sure it will wait for `process.MainWindowTitle` before closing**  (or any other solution that would solve this problem).

Moreover, at the same time, another method might be running a `ReadProcessMemory`, which would crash too.

How can I solve this?

PS: Process.Exit event handler doesn't work because it won't be fired before `process.MainWindowTitle`, it will only be fired after the current instruction is finished.
I'm pretty sure that somehow controlling the exit event is the only way to solve this because the HasExit could change at any time, doesn't mather how many checks I have before actually calling a method on the process.

PS2: I just realized this is a TOCTTOU case, which is unsolvable unless I can control the process I opened, so I'm leaving this here just to see if anyone knows a way to do that.

Comment: What's wrong with simply catching the `InvalidOperationException` and treating that as an exited process? When dealing with external processes, there are all kinds of race conditions that are fundamentally unsolveable; your code just needs to be ready to deal with errors that might occur.

Comment: Hey, Peter! Nothing is wrong with catching the exception, I just want to make sure there is no way to synchronize the threads or something, that there is no solution.

Comment: No matter what you do (within reason...if you're ready to rootkit the system and take over the Windows kernel, I guess you can do whatever you want then :) ), the process could be killed without any possibility of synchronizing with it. Just as one must always be ready to catch `FileNotFoundException` even after having just seen `File.Exists()` return `true`, your own code needs to always be prepared for a process to have exited even though the `Process.HasExited` property has just returned `true`.

Comment: I agree 100% with your reasoning.
Process.HasExited would have returnd false though, not true 8P

Comment: _"would have returnd false"_ -- agreed. :)  Now, that said...have you seen this exception occur? I've been browsing through the code for the `Process` class, and it looks to me as though as long as you have not set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`, having the process exit between getting `HasExited` and getting `MainWindowTitle` (or `MainWindowHandle`) should not cause an exception, because the class won't have noticed that the process has exited yet. Maybe the native call to get the handle and/or title itself would lead to an exception, but the managed part of `Process` seems like it wouldn't.

Comment: I might easily have missed something. But if you haven't already, you should probably double-check that you can actually witness the exception you're expecting. :)

Comment: It does happen. The window title is constantly changing depending on user actions. The title is chached in the process object, and if it changes, one must call Refresh to update the title. After I call refresh, if the process exited, I get the exception, and even if it didn' exit before Refresh, it might exit after it and before reading the title, which would give me an invalid title anyway. This also happened when I tried to read the memory once. Maybe because the operations ate executed on another thread (the timer's) the event handler and the check arent syncd

Comment: I don't think it's a thread thing. Must just be that the native calls fail (or I missed something in the managed code that handles this, though I'm pretty sure I didn't). I did a quick test and confirmed that the exception happens even when `EnableRaisingEvents` isn't set `true`. So yes, you have TOCTTOU and there's not really anything you can do about it, short of just being prepared to catch the exception. And like I mentioned before, since the OS can always just kill the process outright, even if you could take over the process and control it, you still can't ensure against the exception.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Even a bug within the process could cause it to crash thus causing my app to crash, totally out of my control. You should post that as answer, I don't think anyone will come up with a solution. It is quite amazing how real time hasExit is, doesnt matter what your program is doing. I think the only way to solve this problem would be to listen to the signal the process sends saying it wants to exit to the kernel and work from that, like they commented on the class source code hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: you can't.

There is a fundamental "time-of-check-to-time-of-use" issue here that you don't have enough control over to solve. The OS is always able to kill the process you are dealing with (either arbitrarily, or due to some failure in the process), between the time you check the `HasExited` property and the time you check the `MainWindowTitle` property.

The `Process` class doesn't do much to enforce getting the exception, but it does enough. In particular, calling `Refresh()` forces the class to "forget" anything it knows about the process, so that it will re-retrieve the information when you ask for it again. This includes the main window handle for the process.

The `Process` class uses the native window enumeration functions to search for the window handle for the known process ID. Since the process has exited, it fails to find the handle, returning a `NULL` value (`IntPtr.Zero` in managed terms). On seeing the null return value, the `Process` class forces the `InvalidOperationException` to be called.

The only reliable solution is to always be prepared to catch the exception. There will always be a chance that between checking for the state and trying to do something that relies on it, that state can change.

While academic, I find it interesting to note that if you set the `EnableRaisingEvents` property, the `Process` class can be (and usually is) even more efficient about detecting the exited process and throwing the exception.

In particular, when the `EnableRaisingEvents` property is set, the `Process` class registers to be notified by the OS (via the thread pool's `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` method) when the process handle is signaled. I.e. the `Process` class does not even need to go through the effort of searching for the main window handle in this case, because it's notified almost instantly if the process exits.

(Of course, there's still potentially an internal race condition, in a very tiny window of opportunity, since the notification may not have arrived yet when the `Process` class checks for the has-exited state, but the process may still have exited before the `Process` class enumerates the windows).

Anyway, this last bit doesn't affect the basic answer; it's just a bit of trivia I learned and found interesting while wandering through [the `Process` source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs). :)

Comment: They did an amazing with the enableraisingevents indeed.